# Fill SVG image with pattern

Tags: html, image, svg

I'm trying to fill SVG image with a pattern in HTML, but I'm not successfull. If I fill with the pattern path, it works. But I cannot apply it onto svg image.

Could you help me please?
Here is [example](http://dev.kozusnikjan.com/kosile/).

Here is example code:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" width="400" height="400">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="image" x="0" y="0" width="400" height="400" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <image x="0" y="0" xlink:href="latka.jpg" width="100" height="100" />
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <image x="0" y="0" width="400" height="400" xlink:href="kosile.svg"  fill="url(#image)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: You'd need to put the fill definition **in** the image file itself. I.e modify kosile.svg with the fill/pattern. Images cannot be changed by the hosting document.

Comment: This question is worthless for future users unless you put the code in the question...

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense to apply a `fill` attribute to an embedded SVG. I assume what you were trying to do is create a tiled background on which to superimpose the linked SVG. The easiest way to do this is by adding a `<rect>` element filled with the background pattern, then put your embedded SVG image on top of this.

Here's an example:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <defs>
    <!-- define a pattern using a yellow tile image -->
    <pattern id="bgimg" x="0" y="0" width="60" height="60"
             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <image x="0" y="0" width="60" height="60"
             xlink:href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9a/Shades_of_yellow.png/60px-Shades_of_yellow.png" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <!-- use this pattern to fill the SVG background -->
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="url(#bgimg)" />
  <!-- Embed another SVG (purple circle) on top of this background -->
  <image x="40" y="40" width="120" height="120"
         xlink:href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5e/FF0084_circle.svg" />
</svg>
```

Comment: What I want to do is this:
I have some a t-shirt and I want to apply patterns to fill this t-shirt...